# Private comments in SharePoint workflows?

Tags: workflow, comments

I am asking myself if there is a possibility in SharePoint to make comments in the workflow that would be visible only to some authorized users.
Let me know should you need further information to handle my question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could log them to a separate list with limited permissions and use an impersonation step so that the data as written as the workflow publisher. This way no matter who is executing the workflow, they will be able to log the private comments.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean that if John, Paul, Bob and Ryan are involved in an approval workflow, John might be the only one to see the comment of Paul but not Bob and Ryan through the procedure you were just mentionning?

Comment: Yes, assuming that you have permission restricted the list so that John has read permission to the list and you (as the workflow publisher) have contribute access to the list.